# Nginx catch and rewrite all requests begining with /api to proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

I want to redirect all requests that have `/api/` (http://example.com/api/) to my proxy application and drop the `/api` in the process. I have tried this but I get a 404 when curling it. It doesn't reach the application, I'm thinking it's something to do with the `rewrite` but I'm not sure if it's correct.

```
location ~ ^/api {
  rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8070;
}
```

The following works when hard-coded. It redirects me to my application `/error`.

```
location = /api/error {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8070/error;
}
```

For example, I want `http://example.com/api/login` to hit my proxy application like so `http://example.com/login`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. The `$1$is_args$args` part passes every thing after the `/api` in the URL. Now when hitting my domain, `example.com/api/something` passes `/something` to my proxy application.

```
location ~/api(.*)$ {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8070$1$is_args$args;
}
```